# React ComponentDidMount LifeCycle Event With Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, lifecycle

Im wondering why this code doesnt work:

```
const PreviewTemParent = React.createClass({
    conponentDidMount : function() {
        let elePreviewParent = React.findDOMNode( this.refs.previewParent );
        console.log( "    elePreviewParent is...", elePreviewParent );
    },
    render : function() {
        return(
            <div
             className = "previewParent"
              ref = "previewParent">
                <div className = "previewContainer">
                    <PreviewTemImgContainer />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I need to use `ref` on the component because once it has been mounted, I want to read the width & height attributes of the `.previewParent` element in order to position the child components `PreviewTemImgContainer`>

The console doesn't report any console.log messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it's caused by typo. You have misspelled the method.

Just change it from `conponentDidMount` to `componentDidMount`.

**EDIT:**
Instead of calling deprecated `React.findDOMNode` switch to `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`.

Comment: OMG! I spent ages on this -_-. Thank you for pointing out the school boy error. Yes, it does work now.